# Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, warnings, html-select

I've this Select component (using material-ui/core 4.9.13) and I have this warning in my console.. this is a render component and that's what I do {...otherProps} {...field}.
I've read that I can fix this using an option like  but it not works for me. Can someone help me?

```
  <Select className={props.selectClassName}
                onChange={handleSelectChange} // does setValue on this field
                onOpen={handleOnOpen} // does something graphic
                displayEmpty={true}
                variant="outlined"
                {...otherProps}
                {...field}
                value={field.value || ''}
        >
            {OPTIONS_ARR
                .map((obj: { label: string, value: string, country?: string }, index: number) =>
                <option
                    className={`${classes.optionStyle} c-pointer`}
                    key={index}
                    value={obj.value}
                    defaultValue={field.value}
                >
                    {obj.label}
                </option>)}
        </Select>
```

Complete warn here

```
Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.
```

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: what is the warning that you have? what is the issue?

Comment: Updated with more infos

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <Select className={props.selectClassName}
            onChange={handleSelectChange} // does setValue on this field
            onOpen={handleOnOpen} // does something graphic
            displayEmpty={true}
            variant="outlined"
            {...otherProps}
            {...field}
            value={field.value || ''}
    >
        {OPTIONS_ARR
            .map((obj: { label: string, value: string, country?: string }, index: number) =>
            <option
                className={`${classes.optionStyle} c-pointer`}
                key={index}
                value={obj.value}
            >
                {obj.label}
            </option>)}
    </Select>
```

Comment: Have you tried giving one of the value from OPTIONS_ARR as hardcoded to value prop in select?

Comment: Now I tried giving only one option but the result is the same